# how to query for meta_value have array

Tags: wp-query, array, meta-value

I have array in post_meta like this:

```
array(
    'option1' => 'true',
    'option2' => 'true',
    'option3' => 'false',
    option4' => 'true',
    'option5' => 'false'
)
```

and I would like to filter `option1` with value true. Can someone  help me?

Comment: MySQL can't peek into database values and perform queries on serialised PHP array contents

Comment: Serialization is a curse: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A21376+serialize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do that via a query. You can request everything then manually filter out items via PHP, but that would be slow.

Instead, you need to address the root problem, that you're storing serialised PHP data in a single field, rather than multiple fields, e.g. you should have an `option1` meta key/value and an `option2` meta key value pair etc

As a sidenote, if you're wanting to use these to filter, perhaps you should be using a taxonomy instead of post meta

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with the meta_compare option:

```
$args = array(
 'meta_key'     => 'option1',
 'meta_value'   => true,
 'meta_compare' => 'LIKE'
);
```

See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query

Comment: This would only be if the data is stored as a different `meta_key`s for each of "option1", "option2" etc. If the values are stored under one key wordpress will serialize them as it's way of storing an array as a string.